# Android ListView Extending BaseAdapter Crashes on Activity Launch

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have an listview as sidebar in my MainActivity.  I wanted to set an listview item color to a custom color in onCreate(). So i am using an BaseAdapter and overriding its view . And i am setting listview to an ArrayAdapter.
But my App crashed on Launch. Can anybody plz help me with this.

This is my `MainActivity` code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

            ArrayList<String > list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("sohail");
            list.add("aziz");
            list.add("hassan");
            CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(this,list);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);


            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {


                    // Show Alert




                }

            });      



         }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

This is the Base Adapter in which i am overriding my view.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by polak_000 on 10/2/13.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context mycontext;
    ArrayList<String> contactsList;
    LayoutInflater minflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        this.mycontext=context;
        contactsList=list;
        minflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
@Override
    public int getCount()
{
    return contactsList.size();
}


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return contactsList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


@Override
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
     if (convertView !=null)
    {
        if (position ==1)
        {
             convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        }
    }
    return  convertView;
}

}
```

And This is my Layout for MainActivity.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/listView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
         android:minHeight="50dp" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Catlog

> 10-02 14:11:22.125: D/AndroidRuntime(2036): Shutting down VM
>       10-02 14:11:22.125: W/dalvikvm(2036): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
>       10-02 14:11:22.215: D/dalvikvm(2036): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 80K, 5% free 2940K/3072K, paused 34ms, total 36ms
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036): java.lang.NullPointerException
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2179)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1247)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1159)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2189)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15848)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>       10-02 14:11:22.225: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a null from getView function in the adapter. You need to make sure that you are implementing getView function as per your need. Here is a guide on how to do it :http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-listview-tutorial/

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=listview+baseadapter&oq=listview+baseadapter&gs_l=youtube.3...32.4999.0.5161.21.18.0.2.2.0.248.2278.8j4j5.17.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.gEkdQq4gFXM This might look like a good resource :)

Comment: Yes, nothing is better than taking out time and learning new things

Answer (score 0):

More clearly, you need to create the view in getView().

Something like:

```
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        try {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.yadda_yadda, null);
            }
        ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this 

1. list item layout **list_item.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:id="@+id/lnrListItem"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


</LinearLayout>

2. list adapter
 public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context mycontext;
        ArrayList<String> contactsList;
        LayoutInflater minflater;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list)
        {
            this.mycontext=context;
            contactsList=list;
            minflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return contactsList.size();
        }


        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {
            return contactsList.get(position);
        }


        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mycontext).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null,false);
                holder.lnrListItem = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lnrListItem);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            if ((position%2)==0) 
            {
                holder.lnrListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN); // odd item background are cyan

            }else{ 
                holder.lnrListItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // even item background are blue
            }
            holder.textView.setText(contactsList.get(position));

            return  convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            LinearLayout lnrListItem;
            TextView textView;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create custom view for your listview then you have to set the custom layout in your `getView()` method using `LayoutInflater` and return that view in getView() method then only you will be able to set the color on that view. Otherwise getView will always retrun null in `convertView`. Try as below in your `getView()` method.

> ```
>      @Override
>     public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
>     {
>         ViewHolder holder;
>          View m_view=convertView ;
>         if (convertView == null)
>         {
>             holder = new ViewHolder();
>             m_view= LayoutInflater.from(mycontext).inflate(R.layout.list_item,null,false);
>             holder.item= (LinearLayout) m_view.findViewById(R.id.lnrListItem);
>             holder.textView = (TextView) m_view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
>             m_view.setTag(holder);
>         }else{
>             holder = (ViewHolder)m_view.getTag();
>         }
>         if (position==1) 
>         {
>             holder.item.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN); 
>         }else{ 
>             holder.item.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
>         }
>         holder.textView.setText(contactsList.get(position));
>         return  m_view;
>     }
>     class ViewHolder{
>         LinearLayout item;
>         TextView textView;
>     }
> ```